# How do I load images from SCSS in production with Grunt?

Tags: css, path

I have a problem with loading images on production mode. How i build it correctly ?

My scss code for login page:

```
.admin-login {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  .login-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    max-width: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: " ";
    background: url('assets/img/loginbg.jpg');
  }
}
```

And my folder sctructure:

[image: Folder structure]

Which gives me that:

[image: Failure]

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    gulp.src(PATH_JS_SRC + 'main.js')
        .pipe(concat('app.js').on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', function (err) { util.log(util.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_DIST_JS));
});


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src(PATH_CSS_SRC + 'main.scss')
        .pipe(concat('app.css'))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(min({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_DIST_CSS));
});

gulp.task('sass-admin', function(){
    gulp.src(PATH_CSS_SRC + 'admin.scss')
        .pipe(concat('admin.css'))
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(min({ compatibility: 'ie8' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH_DIST_CSS));
});
```

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i solved with this just put image path like this `background: url('/../bluesky/assets/img/loginbg.jpg') no-repeat;` Just need whole of project path.

Answer (score 0):

Your SCSS is calling the image at `dist/css/assets/img/loginbg.jpg` but the path to the actual image is at `/assets/img/loginbg.jpg`.

A quick fix would be to copy your current image to the right path with `mv /assets/img/loginbg.jpg /dist/css/assets/img/loginbg.jpg` in the terminal, but we'd need to know the framework or environment you're using and see the rest of your Gulp file and entire project structure to help beyond that.